# Layers are not Responding in ArcGIS Online Webmap

Tags: layers, arcgis-online, performance

I am using the same layer for six layers in this webmap: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a69b1cbde859433ba816ab0e036712b8.

I am getting a "not responding" error and only half of the layers are drawing properly.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the latest update to Chrome. This issue takes place when a second request is made to the same resource (your layers in the map). The browser does not handle this correctly and then you get the failures. An issue has been logged for Chrome, I currently do not know when the fix will be rolled out but can update this post when it does happen.

Answer (score 0):

There are now two known bugs related to Chrome 52.0.2743.116 and ArcGIS Online. ESRI is waiting on Chrome developers to push a new update.

Defect Id : BUG-000098445

---

- If you duplicate a layer (i.e. "copy") a layer within an AGOL map, or have two layers with the same web address source, the map will fail to load correctly.
- See this thread: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/181308

---

- If you share any hosted feature layer with "Everyone" specifically, this layer will also fail to load correctly and will cause any map that contains it to fail to load correctly as well. ESRI was able to replicate this issue on their end.
- See this thread: https://geonet.esri.com/message/630536

---

**EDIT 9/12/16 Chrome update 53.0.2785.101 has fixed the issue.**